# Changing an elements style with useRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How would I change these speed dials colors one at a time to something when a function is called.

```
                 const dial = useRef();

                       <SpeedDial.Action 
                        color={???}
                        ref={dial}
                        icon={lisaaIcon}
                        title={`Lisää sarjan 1 tiedot`}
                        onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
                        />
                        <SpeedDial.Action
                        color={???}
                        ref={dial}
                        icon={lisaaIcon}
                        title={`Lisää sarjan 2 tiedot`}
                        onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
                        />
                        <SpeedDial.Action 
                        color={???}
                        ref={dial}
                        icon={lisaaIcon}
                        title={`Lisää sarjan 3 tiedot`}
                        onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
                        />
```

I'm calling dial.current.style.color = 'red' for example in a function, but it doesn't seem to work. The speed dial component can receive a color prop. Or would there be another better way to track which one of the dials was pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style attribute in html is a string. Try changing it to `dial.current.style = 'color: red'`.

Edit:

You typically use state for this.

```
const [activeDial, setActiveDial] = useState (null);

return (
<>
    <Dial
        color={activeDial === 1 ? "red" : ""}
        onPress={e => setActiveDial(1)}> ... </Dial>

    <Dial
        color={activeDial === 2 ? "red" : ""}
        onPress={e => setActiveDial(2)}> ... </Dial>
</>
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but do 3rd party components not take refs, unless provided in the component's code?

Comment: refs are for html elements. A custom component would not automatically give you a ref prop.

Comment: What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: I added to my answer.